# Removing the .0's off data when Python reads data from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have successfully gotten the volumes to add up correctly, but it is returning the volume as a decimal. All volumes in the CSV file are whole numbers. I would like to have them without the decimal part.

Code is below.

```
import pandas as pd

datagrid = pd.read_csv("Daily Receipts.csv")
daily_vols = datagrid.groupby("Txn")["Scan Volume"].sum()
print(daily_vols)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the number has significant digits after the decimal point? I would expect them to all end with `.00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `sum` with `pandas` it converted the results to float.

Use [**`astype(int)`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) <--- Link to Docs

```
import pandas as pd

datagrid = pd.read_csv("Daily Receipts.csv")
daily_vols = datagrid.groupby("Txn")["Scan Volume"].sum().astype(int)
print(daily_vols)
```

Comment: This is exactly want I need. Thanks piRSquared

Answer (score 0):

this will do it :

```
import pandas as pd

datagrid = pd.read_csv("Daily Receipts.csv")
daily_vols = datagrid.groupby("Txn")["Scan Volume"].sum()
daily_vols = [ int(x) for x in daily_vols ]
print(daily_vols)
```